# Best Practice for Managing Tomcat Instances

Tags: linux, tomcat

We are in the process of moving our Java app servers from Resin to Tomcat running on RHEL4 - this is has been forced on us by changes adopted by our third party vendor. I want to make sure we are adopting best practice with regards to the management of Tomcat - can anyone make recommendations on best practice, tools, processes that we should look to adopt ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Resin uses config files, Tomcat uses config files.  Whatever method you use for managing your configurations (Puppet, Chef, cfengine, etc.) would apply to both.  Can I ask what, exactly, you're looking for best practices on...?

Answer (score 2):

You could install either LambdaProbe or it's fork [PSIProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) which will give you a Manager view into the app/apps for monitoring, deployment and maintenance. Both are open source products and usage is very similar to the default Tomcat Manager app.
Though LambdaProbe does not seem to be maintained any more.